# How can i get the details of new transactions from a specific collection using web.py?

Tags: python, ethereum, web3py

For the past few days, ive been trying to make a script that can alert me whenever an asset from a collection (defined by me) gets sold. Whenever this happens, it should display the seller, buyer, price and show the image of the nft itself. (The main goal is to make a twitter bot alerting, but i only have problem with the web3.py side of it.) I already have the seller, buyer and price but sadly i cant figure out, how could i download the nft. Also, the code is a bit mess, i dont really want to stick to it. If anyone got a better solution i would really appreciate it!

```
from web3 import Web3
import requests

# Connect to an Ethereum node using Infura
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(''))

# Define the ERC-20 contract address and ABI
contract_address = ''
contract_abi = ''''''
contract = web3.eth.contract(address=contract_address, abi=contract_abi)
transfer_filter = contract.events.Transfer.createFilter(fromBlock='latest')

ETHERSCAN_API_KEY = ""

def handle_transfer_event(event):
    transaction_hash = event.transactionHash.hex()
    transaction_data = get_transaction_data(transaction_hash)
    print(transaction_data)

# Function to get transaction data using Etherscan API
def get_transaction_data(transaction_hash):
    url = f'https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=proxy&action=eth_getTransactionByHash&txhash={transaction_hash}&apikey={ETHERSCAN_API_KEY}'

    # Send a GET request to the Etherscan API
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.json()

    # Check if the response contains an error message
    if 'error' in data:
        print(f"Error: {data['error']['message']}")
        return None, None, None, None, None

    # Extract the 'from', 'to', and 'value' from the response
    result = data['result']
    seller = result['from']
    buyer = result['to']
    value = result['value']

    # Extract the ERC-721 token transferred (if any)
    input_data = result['input']
    if input_data != '0x':
        function_signature = input_data[:10]
        if function_signature == '0x23b872dd':  # Transfer function signature
            token_address = '0x' + input_data[34:74]  # Assuming the token address is at a fixed position
            token_id = '0x' + input_data[74:]
            return seller, buyer, value, token_address, token_id
    decimal_value = int(value, 16)
    decimal_eth_value = decimal_value / 10 ** 18
    return seller, buyer, decimal_eth_value, None, None

print("start")
# Continuous loop to check for new events
while True:
    for event in transfer_filter.get_new_entries():
        print("uj")
        handle_transfer_event(event)
```

I tried to search for something on the internet, but sadly couldnt find any exact tutorials or documentation for this problem im facing.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. It is not possible to provide a specific answer without you providing sufficient information to understand your problem. Please see: [Why is Can someone help me? not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)  for more details.